# If my pages is the only one ranking for a search term, and a new site starts to optimize for it, will they outrank me?

Tags: seo, ranking

If i wrote an article on a keyword phrase with zero global monthly search and my page is indexed by google, when I try to search by those keywords, My article is the only one displayed in google search.

NOW, somehow, I start getting thousands of traffic suddenly from those keywords phrases.

Some popular sites saw my keywords niche popularity and traffic, and posted some articles on the same keyword niches as mine.

My question is **will my article position slide down under those popular sites, just the reason that they are popular?**

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what will happen because we don't know enough about the other site's pages to attempt to figure it out. But if their onpage SEO is better, or they have better incoming links to their pages, they *should* outrank you. Such niche phrases are easy to make movement in due to the low barrier top entry (few sites are optimized for it). So one or two quality links, or even just a site that interlinks its pages properly, can mean a very high, or even #1 ranking, for such low volume search terms.

Comment: thanks for explaining it in yet another simple and interesting way. So at last, we have to maintain the SEO even after finding niche phrases. Right?

Comment: There shouldn't any "maintaining" other then trying to get more links to your pages. But that tends to happen naturally if the content is strong enough.